# How to override `R CMD INSTALL` compilation flags from `Makevars` with `--configure-args` and `--configure-vars`?

Tags: c++, r, linux

Usually when I install an R package from source, it's a `*.tar.gz` file. I want to mess around with some of the `./src/Makevars` flags without untarring, editing the `Makevars`, retarring, and then installing. So I am trying to use `R CMD INSTALL --configure-args=... --configure-vars=...`. (I'm on linux.)

However when I set `R CMD INSTALL --configure-args="-std=c++0x" BoomSpikeSlab.tar.gz`, `gcc` (or `cc1plus`) is still reading the old command `-std=c99` from the `Makevars` file.

Kurt Hornik addressed the way to call this in more detail than `man R CMD` [here](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2001-July/014279.html), but I'm not sure how to get it to "force" the configuration argument I'm passing on top of the default one.

Answer (score 4):

You can try this:

1. creating a `.R` folder in your home,
2. inside, creating a `Makevars` file,
3. writing in this file something like

   ```
   CC = gcc -std=c++0x
   ```

Comment: That does override all three of `R CMD INSTALL --configure-args`, `/etc/R/Makevars`, _and_ `/package/src/Makevars`. But how do you get `--configure-args` to actually do anything?

Comment: I guess it depends whether the package accepts `--configure-args` or not.